# Why I'm getting the GET method?

Tags: php, android, html, email, mobile

I have a simple html code with this form:

```
 <form id="check-user" class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all" data-ajax="false" method="post" action="./second.php">
            <fieldset>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="username">Enter your username:</label>
                    <input type="text" value="" name="username" id="username"/>
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="password">Enter your password:</label>
                    <input type="password" value="" name="password" id="password"/>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" data-theme="b" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

In any browser, even in my phone with the previously code it works fine when I push the submit button, on my php server log it appears

> "POST /test/second.php HTTP/1.1" 200 699 ...

and I can get the POST variables in php.

Next, this html code I send it as an email (gmail), and If I push the submit button, on gmail on my desktop browser works fine :)

But If I open this email, through my phone (gmail app for iphone, also android I've tried) I get this from the php server log

> GET /test/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1546 ...

Why I'm receiving a GET as the method?? Or how can I make better requests from mobile devices ???

Someone else have to deal with this before ??

Thanks for any answers about this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may find that forms are not recommended to be embedded in to emails. Most web-based email platforms do not support form functionality. You're best to provide an external link to your form.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response, I've ended using an external link using mailto.

I've also have to say that the reason I was getting a GET response is because the apps in a mobile phone are know as hybrid, they are not fully html, so they have security policies when one calls to another app (which is this case).
In my php i was receiving a GET method, cause the app was just opening the url, which by default is a get...

Thanks you.